# Expected value of bounded function of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I have the following problem, let $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}, X$ random variables in some probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$, such that $X_n$ converges to $X$ in $L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$. Now consider a continuous function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with at most quadratic growth. Is the bound on the growth of $f$ enough to conclude that

\begin{equation*}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{E}[f(X_n)] = \mathbb{E}[f(X)]\end{equation*} I would like to apply the dominated convergence theorem but I cannot find an upper bound independent of $n$. Any idea on how to prove the statement or, if it is false, any counterexample would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is $f$ used?

Comment: You meant  $Ef(X_n) \to Ef(X)$ when you typed $EX_n \to EX$

Comment: yes, sorry for the typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sketch of proof:

(1) $X_n^{2} \to X$ in $L^{1}$

(2) $(X_n^{2})$ is uniformly integrable (by (1))

(3) $(f(X_n))$ is uniformly integrable (because $|f(x) | \leq C x^{2}$)

(4) Every subsequence of $(X_n)$ has  a further subsequence which converges almost surely. Almost sure convergence and uniform integrability imply convergence of the expectations.

Comment: Should it be $f(X_n)$ in (3)?

Comment: @cinnamicacid Yes, corrected.